# Creating multi-line email body in powershell

Tags: email, powershell

I keep getting error when I am trying to implement multiple line email body. I am suspecting bad syntax. Can't find any example online. Any suggestions?

Error: `Unexpected token 'EmployeeName"] to $AccountExpire"' in expression or statement.`

```
$subject = "Email for $item["EmployeeName"]. Date expire $AccountExpire"
$body=@"                            
Name:  $item["Employee"]
Class: Contractor
Depart: $item["Depart"]
Region: $item["Region"]
Manager: $item["Manager"]
New Date: $NewDate                          
"@                      
SendUpdateEmail($subject,$Body)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting. Where is `$item` defined? Coming from a csv file and a loop I guess? Those variables might not expand in the here string properly.

Comment: Try using single quotes for the field name instead of double quotes, like `['EmployeeName']`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to escape those array index operations with a subexpression (`$()`):

```
$subject = "Email for $($item["EmployeeName"]). Date expire $AccountExpire"
```

Same goes for multi-line strings (or *here-strings* as they're formally called):

```
$body=@"                            
Name:  $($item["Employee"])
Class: Contractor
# and so on...                 
"@
```

---

Personally, I'd go for a multi-line template and use the `-f` format operator to fill in the values:

```
$bodyTemplate=@'
Name: {0}
Class: Contractor
Depart: {1}
Region: {2}
Manager: {3}
New Date: {4}
'@
$body = $bodyTemplate -f $item["Employee"],$item["Depart"],$item["Region"],$item["Manager"],$NewDate
```

When using `-f`, you can also format different types of data, so if `$NewDate` is a `[DateTime]` object, you could control formatting for that inside the template, eg.:

```
@'
Date: {0:HH:mm:ss}
'@ -f (Get-Date)
```

which would produce:

```
Date: 14:55:09
```

(assuming you did this a five to 3 in the afternoon)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen.... sorry... that was silly. It was the syntax highlighting screwing with me.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, prettify doesn't recognize PowerShell escape sequences very well ;)

Comment: I tried the first method and still geting error at $body=@" line and stating its missing the terminator "@ but thats not true.

Comment: Make sure that the opening `@"` is the last thing on its line, and make sure that the closing `"@` is the first thing on its line. No spaces or anything after the opening or before the closing on their respective line. By the way, I use option 2 with the `{0}` and `-f` in production scripts that send thousands of emails daily (great for injecting things into nicely formatted HTML email bodies!). It works wonderfully!

Comment: After spending hours i learned that you cant have any tab space or regular space before declaring this otherwise you get some nasty error. Thanks Mathias for your help. it worked.

Comment: @NinjaCowgirl thanks for posting this, you  just saved me a lot time.